# using sqlmapper.query in dapper with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dapper, dynamicparameters

I am creating a web app using web api mvc and I am using dapper.

Here is a scenario where I want to get the data in a list by validating user info

```
DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
param.Add("@fname", std.Fname);
param.Add("@lname", std.Lname);
param.Add("@action", "L");
IList<student> studlist = SqlMapper.Query<student>(con, "Stud_IUDV", param).ToList();
return studlist.ToList();
```

Here I want to get the data by validating these params and my storedprocedure looks like

```
if(@action='L')
//validation with select command

else
//select all data
```

and I am suppose to get

```
(validation with select command)
```

but else part of my storedprocedure is executing

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: If the problem is with the stored procedure, you might need to post more of that.

Comment: Also, you don't need to provide an ampersand (@) when adding parameter names. `param.Add("fname", std.Fname);`

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(@action='L')
  BEGIN
    //validation with select command
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    //select all data
  END
```

This will solve your sql problem.